# phpmyadmin connection fails once config file is moved to top directory

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, iis-8.5

So I have a Windows server 2012 r2 AWS instance running IIS 8.5, mysql 5.6.27 and phpmyadmin 4.4.15.  (Made to specification rather than preference).

MySQL is setup and accessible through MySQL workbench on localhost, all credentials are correct and working.

With PHPmyadmin I am seeing an odd problem.  When I have my config.inc file in the /config directory a connection can be made by phpmyadmin to the MySQL db.  However when I move the config file to the top level phpmyadmin directory and delete the config directory I get an error:

"Cannot log in to the MySQL server"

when trying to login to phpmyadmin.  If I recreate the /config directory and place the config file back in there I am able to make a connection again.  Below is a copy of my config.inc file, I have tested the using localhost and 127.0.0.1 for the host.  The same issue occurs with both.  I have checked file permissions and can confirm that full read write access is available on the whole phpmyadmin directory

```
<?php
/*
* Generated configuration file
* Generated by: phpMyAdmin 4.4.15 setup script
* Date: Wed, 14 Oct 2015 10:43:33 +0100
*/

/* Servers configuration */
$i = 0;

/* Server: somename[1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'somename';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = 3300;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'xxxxxxx';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'xxxxxxx';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'xxxxxx';

/* End of servers configuration */

$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xxxxxxx';
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
$cfg['BZipDump'] = false;
$cfg['ForceSSL'] = true;
$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en';
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
?>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: You can't move application files around.

Comment: In the documentation I have read and the guides found through google this appears to be a standard step in the setup.

Comment: Yes, you need to set up config.inc, but it must be in the directory that phpMyAdmin expects to find it

Comment: Once the file has been saved, it must be moved out of the config/ directory and the permissions must be reset, again as a security measure:               From: http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html

Comment: Read again... you are doing the wrong thing

Comment: perhaps I'm being a bit thick but the following suggest to me that you move the file out of /config, check permissions and then delete /config dir?.........                                                                                                             mv config/config.inc.php .         # move file to current directory
chmod o-rw config.inc.php          # remove world read and write perms
rm -rf config                      # remove not needed directory

Comment: another reference found on phpmyadmin wiki ......... "config.inc.php is the name of phpMyAdmin's configuration file. It must exist in the phpMyAdmin top level directory (where you can find the Documentation.html as well) but not in ./config/ or any other subfolder and must be readable by php."

Comment: Yes, you're doing the right thing. I'm not sure what user2182349 means by "you can't move application files around" since you're not moving the application. The 'user' and 'password' fields aren't used because your auth_type is cookie, and I suggest also removing the controluser and controlpass until you get it working. Try logging in to MySQL Workbench and checking the connection details (the SQL query `STATUS;` is a good way to do so); compare hostname, username, and connection type with your config.inc.php.

Comment: In your libraries/vendor_config.php, how are defined CONFIG_DIR and CONFIG_FILE ?

Comment: /**
 * Directory where configuration files are stored.
 * It is not used directly in code, just a convenient
 * define used further in this file.
 */
define('CONFIG_DIR', './');

/**
 * Filename of a configuration file.
 */
define('CONFIG_FILE', CONFIG_DIR . 'config.inc.php');